# Alice security vulnerability possibility

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-pub

Alice intercepts HTTP requests and persists them to display them in the UI, does this create security vulnerabilities and enable man-in-the-middle attacks or help break the SSL layer?

https://pub.dev/packages/alice

Alice implemented and is up and running. Need to know the security vulnerabilities associated with implementing the package.

Answer (score 1):

It could.  You're adding a dependency to your app which wraps the native http implementation and intercepts it.  It literally is a man in the middle attack on your own app by your own app.  While I don't know of anything wrong with this dependency, I would carefully audit the code before using it, and reaudit every new version before updating it, to make sure the developers don't deploy bugs or intentional malware.

Comment: Yeah, figured the same and abandoned Alice over the security concerns. Too much overhead in auditing the package.